# The child node "providers" at path "security" must be configured SonataAdmin FosUser

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I'm struggling to install SonataAdminBundle with FOSuserBundle.

I'm following the manual at https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/2-2/doc/reference/installation.html but at the last step, to generate the Bundle,
I have the error "The child node "providers" at path "security".

I've configured nicely the providers part in app/config/config.yml. What did I do wrong ?

PS : I'm using the 2.8 version of Symfony.

Thanks !

Comment: You probably have a misconfiguration in security.yaml or must have skipped a step somewhere. Can you post it's contents here?

Answer (score 0):

i'll try to help, i had same problem. it was logical error in app/config/security.yml

My bad was is add this code in the middle

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
        handler: app.security.handler.role
```

when i add it in the end of file - all works good !

The child node "providers" at path "security - meaning that in your **security** can't find node **providers**  must be smth like this:

```
security:
...
\t encoders:
...
\t providers:
...
\t firewalls:
...
\t access_control:
...
sonata_admin:
```

\t-tab symbol